# How to delete database entries with one query < actual date with year month and day value in separate fields?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a mysql db with 3 fields in table (year, month, day) which represents dates

```
year | month | day
2019 | 10 | 24
2018 | 5  | 4
2018 | 8  | 23
```

Now I want to delete all entries in db smaller than actual month and year.
Is that possible within one mysql query and how?

I tried ...

```
"DELETE FROM db WHERE year < ".date("Y")." AND month < ".date("m");
```

But that leaves some entries in DB for example 2018-11-28

Any ideas?

Comment: use `or` instead of `and`

Comment: that deletes also db entries from 2019!

Comment: Why do you have year, month and day as separate columns?

Comment: that was not my desicion :( any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this purely in SQL:

```
DELETE FROM db WHERE (year < YEAR(NOW())) or (year = YEAR(NOW()) AND month < MONTH(NOW()))
```

If the year is 2018 or less or if the year is 2019 and the month is less than August it will delete all records.

Answer (score 0):

"DELETE FROM db WHERE year < ".YEAR(getdate())." AND month < ".MONTH(getdate());

YEAR(getdate()) will get you the current year 
MONTH(getdate()) will get you the current month

Comment: thanks, but you missunderstood! data -> date("Y") comes from php script .. I don't search for equivalent on mysql .. need to delete all entries where concatenated dates are smaller then actual month/year.